# touchesMoved(): is it the only finger-tracking API? and is it accurate?

Tags: ipad, touches, touchesmoved, low-level-api

I'm writing an iPad application that needs to time the finger movement very precisely, so I am keen on getting the best performance and accuracy I can. I have two questions about this:

1. For intercepting finger position on screen, must I use touchesMoved(), or is there a lower-level API?
2. Does anyone know whether touchesMoved() returns the exact position on screen, or does the iPad perform some interpolation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You have 3 ways to intercept finger positions:
   a) UIResponder Delegate metods:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
```

b) UIGestureRecognizer's methods

c) You also can override **- (void)sendEvent:(UIEvent *)event;** within UIApplicationDelegate or UIWindow to catch UIEvents - but this method is not recommended.

All this methods work with UITouch that contain touch **point**. This point calculated by device hardware, so you can't affect precision.

And the last: minimal recommended touch area is 44x44. If you touch area will be smaller then users will fill yourself discomfortable working with your software.

Answer (score 0):

Touches are not very precise, because fingers are not very precise (*much* less so than a mouse cursor), and because the tracking hardware isn't very precise (because it doesn't need to, because of finger size - it *does not work* without significant touched area).

That being said, the iDevices have very good touchscreens compared to many other capacitive touch devices. I'm just not sure pixel-precision is attainable in practice.

It's easy to experiment with this, though.